# Using a Raspberry Pi as a 5GHz Router to distribute 2.4GHz on a boat

Tags: wifi, usb, openwrt

The topics of using a Raspberry Pi as a router, repeater seem to be well covered but my attempts to change those to my boat's needs have been...unfruitful.

I'd like to connect the marina's included WiFi at 5GHz using a weatherproof USB 5G Wifi with directional antenna. (sailboat masts create a LOT of interference, Steel/Aluminum boats are basically a wall of Grounding)
I picture the Raspberry Pi would then act as a Router at 2.4Ghz on another USB dongle for my older instruments, sensors, tablets, PCs inside the boat. My Issue is I cannot plug into the marina's LAN port as most router instructions require. I DO have the marina WiFi SSID and my assigned password. While visiting other marinas, the weatherproof WiFi would then be configured or select a new SSID and password, while the boat's internal WiFi 2.4GHz connections all remain the same.

I can't seem to wrap my head around OpenWRT well enough to use two USB external WiFi dongles.

I have two RPi3s and am open to buying whatever hardware is compatible/proven to get this to work

Is this approach reasonable?
Should I try to configure the RaspberryPi as a Wifi to LAN router (backwards) and plug it into a standard WiFi Router?(I think they all assume the reverse direction of LAN to WiFi, not WiFi as the ISP. Some System Engineering guidance would be helpful too.
Thanks in Advance